# "exercise book — тетрадь" Что за конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Вот примеры, взятые из электронного словаря:

> exercise book  — тетрадь
>   drawing block  — блокнот для рисования, тетрадь
>   workbook |ˈwɜːrkbʊk|  — рабочая тетрадь, сборник упражнений, конспект

Можно ли эту запись считать предложением, где слово на английском — подлежащее, а перевод — сказуемое? Или это скорее техническая запись, некая трансформация традиционной пунктуации, использование схожих принципов, но для специфической задачи? И здесь говорить о предложениях уже нельзя?